# What is the MPI_Bcast() for in this C++ program?

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, mpi

I started to learn MPI and took this tutorial code example from [Russian IT blog Habrahabr](https://habr.com/en/post/121235/):

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

double Fact(int n)
{ 
    if (n==0) return 1;
    else return n*Fact(n-1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int myid;
    int numprocs;
    int i;
    int rc;

    long double drob,drobSum=0,Result, sum;
    double startwtime = 0.0;
    double endwtime;

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (rc= MPI_Init(&argc, &argv)) { 
        cout << "Launch error" << endl;
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
    } 

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs); 
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid); 

    if (myid == 0) {
        startwtime = MPI_Wtime();
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (i = myid; i <= n; i += numprocs)
    { 
        drob = 1/Fact(i);
        drobSum += drob;
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&drobSum, &Result, 1, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    cout.precision(20);

    if (myid == 0)
    {   
        cout << Result << endl; 
        endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
        cout << (endwtime-startwtime)*1000 << endl;      
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is why do they need that

```
MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

there, if the `n` value is set in all processes with the

```
n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

anyways.

Is this just a mistake or it has any purpose? I tested the code and it works OK without it.

I thought maybe broadcast implies some process work flow barrier which is used for correct calculation time measurement or something.

Also I thought maybe it is there because that `n` initialisation goes before the `MPI_Init()` call.
Would I need that `MPI_Bcast()` in this code if I put `n = atoi(argv[1]);` after `MPI_Init()` then?

Comment: `n` is used in the `for` loop right after the broadcast. The reduce does not involve `n` whatsoever.

Comment: If `argv[1]` is set on **all** your MPI tasks, then you do not need to broadcast it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you, but are there any possibilities it might be useful in that case? I updated the question. Could you be more specific about `argv[1]` please. I do not understand how it may help.

Comment: Also note that I fixed the question, sorry posted wrong line of code.

Comment: If the MPI standard does not guarantee `argv[1]` is  set on **all** the ranks, then `n` might be incorrect on ranks > 0. In that case, the broadcast will fix that.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The program uses same args for `MPI_Init()` which it receives in `main()`. I thought all other ranks receive it's arguments.

Comment: I do not know whether this is per the spec, or a given MPI implementation choice. That is why I'd rather suggest you refer to the MPI standard if you want to write portable code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Ok, thanks, updated the question then. Colud you please post an answer because this comments list is quite long already and it is more about answering than question clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything before `MPI_Init()` is [undefined behavior in MPI](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Init.html). If you don't want to broadcast the commandline arguments then you should use `argv` and `argc` after `MPI_Init(&argc, &argv)` because then they will be guaranteed to be available to all tasks.

The code works fine because many MPI implementations make `argv` and `argc` available before the initialization, but you should not rely on this behavior.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about this: "I thought maybe broadcast implies some process work flow barrier which is used for correct calculation time measurement or something."? Could that also be the case?

Comment: You're right that `MPI_Bcast()` does implicitly act like an `MPI_Barrier()`; however, I don't think that has anything to do with executing code before `MPI_Init()`. I suppose you could use it how you would an `MPI_Barrier()` to synchronize before timing something, but it would probably be better to use use a barrier so that your intentions are clear in the code.